# proxy in php script and connect to it via browser

Tags: php, proxy, socks

can i find  any php script that act as  proxy server(socks ,http,..)  and  connect to it via firefox (like  any other proxy server )
(for  example  run script first after  that script act like  proxy,...)
i want  to bypass filtring

i seen this sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy Already , i need  connect to it like  socks proxy

i dont  have  any server for  using  as ssh Tunneling  or install other proxy application in it i have  only  server  and allow run any php screapt in it

tanks

Comment: Are you trying to build your own proxy-server, or are you looking for a finished script? If it's the latter, Stackoverflow is probably not the site to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy server basically does one simple thing: it loads the date (to make it easier I'll assume it's a website in the rest of answer) you request and sends it to you. Because you do not directly connect to the website, it thinks you are at the location that **does** request to page: your server.

There are multiple ways to connect to a proxy server, some use a custom protocol, while you can connect to others using http(s) in a web browser. Because you mention you want to connect to your proxy using Firefox, I'll assume you want a web proxy such as [hidemyass.com](http://hidemyass.com).

When you request a web page on a web proxy, the following things happen in this order:

1. Your computer sends a request to the web proxy. In this request is also the address of the website you want to load;
2. The proxy opens the website you requested. Since a website is basically just a document of data, you open it using a simple function such as `file_get_contents()`. Alternatively, you can use `CURL` for more options and better performance. You save this data in a variable;
3. The proxy has now got the website, but can't show it to the user yet. Because almost every website loads other files (like stylesheets, scripts, images, or even other HTML documents) you also need to load these using your proxy and not with the user's internet connection. The easiest (and not watertight) way to implement this is probably to look for every `http://` in the data and replace it with a request to your proxy server;
4. Now that you've saved the website in a variable on your server, you just need to show it to the user. You can just print it to the screen. Just be sure to pass the correct headers with the requested file!

Please note that this would not be the perfect proxy server: for that you would for example also need to support https requests and check AJAX requests (or disable Javascript altogether, which many proxy servers do). If you just want to use a proxy server, I suggest you take a look at existing ones (or at the comments in the Sourceforge project you linked to, which contains links to better alternatives). But if you find this an interesting project to undertake, good luck!